# How is an $n$ sphere in $m$ dimensions defined?

Tags: real-analysis

How is an $n$ sphere in the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^m$ defined?

Context:

I'm working through an excercise in Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich p417.

It says:

> (a) In the space $\mathbb{R}^k$ a two-dimensional sphere $S^2$ and a circle $S^1$ are situated so that the distance from any point of the sphere to any point of the circle is the same.
> Is this possible?
>
> (b) Consider problem a) for spheres $S^m$, $S^n$ of arbitrary dimension in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Under
> what relation on $m$ , $n$ , and $k$ is this situation possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a $n+1$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, let $x_0\in X$ and $r>0$, and consider the set $\{\,x\in X\colon |x-x_0|=r\,\}$. This would be an $n$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

(Or you could go for a *much* weaker definition: Any subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ that is homeomorphic to the standard $n$-sphere. But I don't think that is the intention in the context you mention.)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, the equations of a $n$-sphere lying in $\Bbb R^m$ with $m\ge n$ are
$$(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2+\cdots+(x_m-a_m)^2=r^2$$
and the equations of an affine manifold with dimension $n$ passing though the center $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$.

But to solve the problem, perhaps this approach would be easier:
Consider a circle in $\Bbb R^k$, centered at the origin, and lying in a plane $H$. The set of points that are at the same distance from the points of the circle, are exactly those in $H^\perp$. Since the dimension of $H^\perp$ is $k-2$, if we want a $S^2$ sphere lying there, we need that $k-2\ge 3$.